# How to define a complex type with the #define directive?

Tags: c, typedef, preprocessor-directive

I'm learning to build complex types. Here I defined a pointer to an array 5 of shorst using `typedef`:

```
typedef short (*mytype)[5];
```

I'm trying to find out how to to the same with the `#define` directive and if it is even feasible. I tried this, but it does not work:

```
#define MYTYPE (short*)[5]
```

It seems like this directive cannot be applied for defining something more complex than a pointer or a struct. So, what is the point here?

Comment: Suggestion: don't hide `*` behing a typedef. The `*` in source code is a good visual note about something being a pointer; in the same way, the absence of `*` is a good indicator something **is not** a pointer. Hiding the `*` in a typedef breaks this visual indication.

Comment: @pmg I only seek educational purposes, this is not of any practical use. Still thanks for the piece of advice, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: The type would be `short (*)[5]`, but that would only be good in certain contexts, such as `casts` or `sizeof` operands, not for declarations. `#define` directives are not particularly for creating aliases for types. Appropriate uses include very short “functions”, providing some substitutions that are useful for customizing software to various environments, or signaling features to turn on/off.

Comment: @EricPostpischil does not work, when specifying `MYTYPE var;` it asks for an identifier or `(`

Comment: @Kaiyaha: As my comment says, it is not good for declarations. And as my comment says, `#define` directives are not for creating aliases for types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so... it is impossible to define such type with `#define` syntactically, right?

Comment: `#define MYTYPE  __typeof(short (*)[5])` if `__typeof` was finally standardized. (It's quite widely supported, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to define a [variable of a pointer to array type] with the #define directive?

You may just use a function macro.

```
#define MYTYPE(name)  short (*name)[5]
int main() {
    short arr[5];
    MYTYPE(a) = &arr;
    typedef MYTYPE(mytype);
}
```

> what is the point here?

There's is no point - preprocessor is a string replacement tool that is generally not aware of C syntax. Use a `typedef` to define an alias for a type.

Comment: Well, that was the most obvious solution, but I just wanted `MYTYPE` to look exactly like a regular type. Is that possible?

Comment: plak plak plak :(